How to implement bounce effect for row with horizontal scroll?
I have Row with .horizontalScroll() and I need bounce animation effect. That is, when the list appears, it scrolls forward a little, and then returns back. At the same time, I need a spring effect when returning the scroll back.
Here is my implementation:
val scrollState = rememberScrollState()
val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
val bounceDistance = 150
    
LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    val animatable = Animatable(scrollState.value.toFloat())

    coroutineScope.launch {
        animatable.animateTo(
            targetValue = bounceDistance.toFloat(),
            animationSpec = tween(
                durationMillis = 200,
                easing = LinearOutSlowInEasing
            )
        )
        scrollState.scrollTo(animatable.value.toInt())
        animatable.animateTo(
            targetValue = 0f,
            animationSpec = spring(
                dampingRatio = 0.4f,
                stiffness = Spring.StiffnessLow
            )
        )
        scrollState.scrollTo(animatable.value.toInt())
        animatable.animateTo(
            targetValue = bounceDistance * 0.3f,
            animationSpec = tween(
                durationMillis = 400,
                easing = LinearOutSlowInEasing
            )
        )
        scrollState.scrollTo(animatable.value.toInt())
        animatable.animateTo(
            targetValue = 0f,
            animationSpec = spring(
                dampingRatio = 0.6f,
                stiffness = Spring.StiffnessLow
            )
        )

        scrollState.scrollTo(animatable.value.toInt())
    }
}

However, it all looks very unsmooth and slow. What am I doing wrong?
P.S. This is needed to hint to the user that the component has horizontal scrolling.

Your code doesn't work properly because you manually call scrollState.scrollTo 4 times after each animation. You should call scrollState.scrollTo when animatable.value updates, for example:
val scrollState = rememberScrollState()
val bounceDistance = 150
val animatable = remember { Animatable(0f) }

LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    animatable.animateTo(
        targetValue = bounceDistance.toFloat(),
        animationSpec = tween(
            durationMillis = 200,
            easing = LinearOutSlowInEasing
        )
    )
    animatable.animateTo(
        targetValue = 0f,
        animationSpec = spring(
            dampingRatio = 0.4f,
            stiffness = Spring.StiffnessLow
        )
    )
    animatable.animateTo(
        targetValue = bounceDistance * 0.3f,
        animationSpec = tween(
            durationMillis = 400,
            easing = LinearOutSlowInEasing
        )
    )
    animatable.animateTo(
        targetValue = 0f,
        animationSpec = spring(
            dampingRatio = 0.6f,
            stiffness = Spring.StiffnessLow
        )
    )
}

LaunchedEffect(animatable.value) {
    scrollState.scrollTo(animatable.value.toInt())
}


Instead of making bounce animation manually you can use tween animation spec with EaseOutBounce easing:

val animatable = remember { Animatable(0, Int.VectorConverter) }
LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    animatable.animateTo(
        targetValue = bounceDistance,
        animationSpec = tween(
            durationMillis = 200,
            easing = LinearOutSlowInEasing
        )
    )
    animatable.animateTo(
        targetValue = 0,
        animationSpec = tween(
            durationMillis = 1000,
            easing = EaseOutBounce
        )
    )
}

LaunchedEffect(animatable.value) {
    scrollState.scrollTo(animatable.value)
}

